# Can I use tokens in Jenkins job config?

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to use the Jenkins job name in the config:

- Maven root POM should be: {JOB_NAME}\pom.xml
- SCM sub path should be: {JOB_NAME}

Are there tokens I could use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SCM the answer is 'yes' - use ${JOB_NAME} (e.g. `svn://myserver/myrepo/trunk/${JOB_NAME}`).

In Maven build step it does not work. However, you may try using a custom workspace (push 'Advanced' button under 'Build' -> check 'use custom workspace') that contains ${JOB_NAME} (e.g. `C:\workspaces\${JOB_NAME}`) as a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately we're using AccuRev SCM, which doesn't seem to support that token in its config. Thank you anyway - that it helpful